# php pdo bindparam allowing bad parameter

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

The following block of code runs successfully - echos "line 18 0"
The parameter $oginURL does not exist but it doesn't throw an error. Is that correct behavior?

```
  try {
    $sql = "SELECT idrecordLogins, loginAddress, loginAttempts, failedLoginAttempts FROM recordLogins
                    WHERE loginAddress = :loginURL" ;
     $stmt = $DBH->prepare($sql);
     echo "line 14 $oginURL";
     $stmt->bindParam(':loginURL', $oginURL, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
     $stmt->execute();
     if ($stmt->rowcount() == 0 ) {
         // add it
         $x =  $stmt->rowcount();
         echo "line 18 $x" ;
         return 'success' ;
     }
     else {
        // update it
         $x =  $stmt->rowcount();
         echo "line 25 $x" ;
        return 'success';
     }
 }
 catch (ErrorException $e) {
    echo "line 31";
 }
```

}

Comment: Did you configure PDO to throw useful exceptions? By default, except for initial connection, it _errors silently_. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Oh, but this is not PDO's doing  - if you don't have PHP configured to report errors, you won't see the undefined variable error.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` PDO doesn't care that the variable does not exist, and will just use `NULL`, but PHP will complain if you instruct it to.

Comment: I think so - here is my login

Comment: sorry - (pressed enter) stripped version of login -    
          $dsn = "mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$database."; charset=utf8";
          // if connection fails for any reason, a PDOException will be thrown
          $DBH = new PDO( $dsn, $user, $password );
          // in this case these are probably not required
          $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true );
          $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
          $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,  false);
        return $DBH;

       }   // end of function

Comment: I had set Display errors off & intended to write them to my log. Can I catch that error without turning Display on?

Comment: PHP doesn't entirely consider it to be an error and you cannot catch errors .Exceptions are not universal in PHP - you just need to check isset () on the variable and not act if it is empty. You have to code that in. PHP cannot handle it automatically.

Comment: okay, I understand it know. I'll mark it solved. Thanks